# Created nested json from dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

```
data={'category':['Medical','Medical','Research','Medical','Research'], 
       'countrycode':['US','CAN','US','CAN','US'],
       'stateCode':['AK','AB','MO','NT','OK'],
       'statecount':[600,100,200,760,90]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Given is my input dataframe. I want to produce a nested json output as follows :

```
{
  'Medical' : { 
                'US' : {'AK':600,'OK':90}
                'CAN': {'AB':160, 'NT':760}
               },
  'Research' : { 
                'US' : {'MO':200,'OK':90}
               }
 }
```

I have been trying to play around with the following code, but cannot seem to get countrycode as second level.

```
df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: x.groupby('countrycode').apply(lambda y:y[['stateCode','statecount']]).to_json(orient='records'))
```

Any help or direction is appreciated, new to python.

Answer (score 1):

One efficient option using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = {}
for (k1,k2), g in df.groupby(['category', 'countrycode']):
    out.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = g.set_index('stateCode')['statecount'].to_dict()
```

Alternatively, less efficient but maybe more flexible:

```
{k1: {k2: g2.set_index('stateCode')['statecount'].to_dict()
      for k2, g2 in g.groupby('countrycode')}
 for k1, g in df.groupby('category')}
```

Output:

```
{'Medical': {'CAN': {'AB': 100, 'NT': 760},
             'US': {'AK': 600}},
 'Research': {'US': {'MO': 200, 'OK': 90}}}
```